# How to detect if a browser supports dark mode

Tags: javascript, css, browser, darkmode

We can use `prefers-color-scheme: dark` to detect if dark mode is activated or not:

```js
const isDarkMode = window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches;
```

Is there a way detect if a browser supports dark mode at all? (By "supports dark mode" I mean the browser automatically changes the default background/text colors of web pages).

In CSS, we can force dark mode with

```css
color-scheme: dark;
```

however, some browsers (Firefox for Android) will ignore it. So I'd like to hide theme selection if dark mode is not available.

Comment: not sure on detecting but you can easily look quickly here https://caniuse.com/?search=color%20scheme

Comment: What do mean by when it's available?, Dark mode is something that you add to the website. If you want to detect whether the browser can detect the OS mode do as you mentioned on the question. is there something that I'm missing?

Comment: @MohamedAbdallah We can force dark mode in CSS with `color-scheme: dark;` but not all browsers will switch to dark mode (i.e. Android Firefox).

Comment: You could try to base your detection on CSS's `@supports (color-scheme: dark) { ... }`.

Comment: @connexo interesting. Any ideas why its "true" when used any string instead of `dark` ? For example `@supports (color-scheme: blahblahblah) { background-color: red; }`

Answer (score 0):

My current solution is to switch between dark and light mode and check if default color has changed between the modes:

```js
const hasDarkMode = function()
{
  const el = document.createElement("div");
  el.style.display = "none";
  document.body.appendChild(el);
  let color;
  /*canvastext - doesn't work in Samsung Internet, initial/unset - doesn't work in Firefox*/
  for(let i = 0, c = ["canvastext", "initial", "unset"]; i < c.length; i++ )
  {
    el.style.color = c[i];
    el.style.colorScheme = "dark";
    color = getComputedStyle(el).color;
    el.style.colorScheme = "light";
    color = color != getComputedStyle(el).color;
    if (color)
      break;
  }
  document.body.removeChild(el);
  return color;
}();

console.log("Dark mode supported:", hasDarkMode);
```

This might not be the most elegant solution, but it seems to be working.

With comment from @connexo we can also test with:

```js
const hasDarkMode = CSS.supports("color-scheme", "dark");

console.log("Dark mode supported:", hasDarkMode);
```

```css
@supports (color-scheme: dark)
{
  .no-dark-mode
  {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>Dark mode is <span class="no-dark-mode">not </span>available</div>
```

Comment: why do you prefer `const hasDarkMode = function()` over `function hasDarkMode ()`?

Comment: Because it doesn't need to be executed more than once.