# Browsers saying dark mode enabled even when not enabled

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, firefox

I'm testing in both Chrome and Firefox. In Firefox I have no plugin, but in Chrome I have the Darkreader plugin for dark mode.

Here is my problematic code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (window.matchMedia && window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches) {
        alert('dark');
    } else {
        alert('light');
    }
});
```

No matter what, whether I have Darkreader disabled in Chrome or am testing in Firefox, I get "dark" mode every time.

The code is seemingly pretty simple - is there a way to fix this code so I get the actual scheme the user is using?

Comment: Is dark mode enabled in your system? also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69956563/how-to-detect-if-a-browser-supports-dark-mode

Comment: Ok, I did not realize your OS's theme mattered here. So, yes, I had dark mode enabled in macOS so I guess that overrides everything. Is there no way to further detect if the user has a plugin or not? Also, the link you posted didn't work - it's giving me dark mode no matter what.